# cmd.exe and set -- not showing variable in my block?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Disclaimer: I'm somewhat of a novice in CMD.EXE

I'm trying, in one line (not in a .BAT file), to find each matching application and launch it. My code:

```
for /R %systemdrive%\ %i in (*myProgram.exe) do (set a=%~fi & "%a%" & pause)
```

Although *a=%~fi* sets the variable, "%a%" won't run anything because %a% is empty. I have to wait until another prompt before "%a%" works.

I suspect the problem is due to not using "setlocal enabledelayedexpansion" but when I write

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & for /R %systemdrive%\ %i in (*myProgram.exe) do (set a=%~fi & "!a!" & pause)
```

I get an error: ""!a!"' is not recognized as an internal or external command."

I'm doing this because I need to remotely support various Windows machines where I can't create and leave a .BAT, so I'm using AutoHotKey (AHK) to dynamically create "one-liners" and where myProgram1.exe may, in practice, be myProgramA.exe or myProgramD.exe.

Comment: Are you writing this in a batch file?

Comment: `setlocal`/`endlocal` only works within a batch file, so if you're working in `cmd`, you need to activate delayed expansion by opening a new instance like `cmd /V:ON`; if you are working in a batch file, you need to double the `%`-signs in front of the `for` variable like `%%i` & `%%~fi`...

Comment: *I suspect the problem is due to*... What problem? You didn't indicate one; just that you changed setlocal as a result of your guesswork. It's difficult to say whether that was the right solution or not, because you didn't explain the initial *problem* you're trying to solve. Can you [edit] to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert, but this does for me what you are describing:

```
@echo off & setlocal & for /R %systemdrive%\ %%i in (*myProgram.exe) do (echo executing %%i & %%i & pause )
```

Though I am interested why you want to do this on a single line...

Comment: Yes, that is better. I rewrote mine to avoid the variable: "for /R %systemdrive%\ %i in (*myProgram1.exe) do ("%~fi" -parameters & pause)", which in AHK is <code>for /R `%systemdrive`%\ `%i in (*%UserInput%) do ("`%~fi" %PARAMS% & pause)</code>

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting an environment variable when you already have a FOR variable with the value you need?

```
for /R %systemdrive%\ %i in (*myProgram.exe) do ("%~fi" & pause)
```